# Haskell: TCO and Lazy evaluation

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, tail-call-optimization

I'm trying to understand why the first `main` does not terminate when `c` is not valid, while the second terminates. From the description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782222/haskell-recursion-and-memory-usage) 
 `main` is just an unevaluated thunk, and `executing` it is just building up the data structure. I'm trying to apply the same principle here and see why the first main does not terminate. If someone can help me understand this part, or give me pointers to understanding this would be great. Apart from this, why is GHCI not able to recognize this as TCO ? does is not fit the definition?

```
main = loop                                                                     
  where                                                                         
   loop =  do                                                                   
     c <- getChar                                                               
     case valid c of                                                            
       Nothing -> return ()                                                     
       Just b  -> print b                                                       
     print c                                                                    
     loop                                                                       

> main :: IO ()
> main = loop
>   where
>   loop =  do
>     c <- getChar
>     case validate c of
>       Nothing -> return ()
>       Just b  -> do
>         print b
>         loop
```

Thanks.

Comment: You realise that [`return`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Instances.html#v:return) is just a library function, and works quite differently from the `return` keyword in procedural languages?

Comment: @leftaroundabout : realized that "something" about this is not correct, as I was hitting "POST", then saw this comment immediately. Thanks.

Comment: there is no way to 'close' a question other than accepting an answer? if so, I need to wait for sometime before I can accept an answer. Will read the stackoverflow documentation. For now, to accept I've to wait 7 more minutes :-) .

Comment: @user3169543 There is no rush to accept an answer. Upvote answers that you find useful and come back, say tomorrow, and accept the one you deem best.  Accepting early means that you are less likely to receive very good answers since answerers may lose interest in the question, and often the first answer may not be correct (or as correct) or complete (or as complete) as following answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tail-call optimization has **nothing** to do with this behaviour. The problem is simply that the first code contains an infinite loop while the second doesn't.

Your first code is similar to the imperative (python-like):

```py
def loop():
    c = getChar()
    if valid c:
        do_something()
    else:
        do_something_else()

    print(c)
    loop()
```

While the latter is similar to:

```py
def loop():
    c = getChar()
    if valid c:
        do_something()
    else:
        do_something_else()
        print(c)
        loop()
```

Note how in the latter case the call to `loop()` is *inside* the branch `else` while in the former it's *outside* and thus is called at every `loop` invocation.

Also note that `return` in Haskell does **not** terminate the function calls. It's just an `IO` action that has a certain value and no side-effects.

For example:

```
main = do
    c <- return 1
    print c
```

In the above code the `return` does **not** prevent the output from `print`.